# Expected probability maximization with binomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, optimization

I need to solve an optimization problem that involves an expected value like 
$$F(n,x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k(1 - p)^{n - k} f(k,x).$$

Here $f(k,x)$ is actually a probability coming from a normal distribution. And what I need, in particular, is to solve a first order condition that involves the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$. Numerically it is OK, but I was wondering how I could obtain a nice analytical form. I tried several things, like replacing $f(k,x)$ with other normal-like distributions, but none worked.

I need this to show some asymptotic properties, so I could use a solution that considers the case when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Also, approximations are equally welcome.

I can simplify $f$ in the following way.
$$f(k,x)= \Pr[y\geq Ak+B(n-k)+Cx] \text{ where } y\sim N(n,\sigma).$$

And I want to solve

$$\max qF(n,x)+(1-q)G(n,x)$$

with respect to $x$ where $q\in(0,1)$ and
$$G(n,x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k(1 - p)^{n - k} g(k,x)$$
with 
$$g(k,x)=\Pr[y'\leq Ak+B(n-k)+Cx] \text{ where } y'\sim N(-n,\sigma).$$

Comment: what do you mean "a nice analytical form"?

Comment: @E.J. Well I want to have the maximizer $x^*$ written simply, to use it elsewhere.